# How to properly open a new Scanner and take input

Tags: java, hyperlink, jsoup, java.util.scanner

I recently stumbled upon the JSoup library, so I decided to experiment with hit by creating a google query program.

The idea is to type in a Google search, take in the number of queries you want to display, display them, **then** ask the user for one more integer for input, which is the index that's displayed next to the link.

The problem is that the new Scanner is never called. It prints the prompt and closes.

**NOTE**: I know I can just go to google myself and search. I'm just experimenting with this new library that scratched that part of my brain that makes me want to look further into something.

Here is the code, and the output **-- Sorry if it's sloppy. Still learning...**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class GoogleSearchJava {

    static int index;
    static String linkHref;

    public static final String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //GET INPUT FOR SEARCH TERM

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Search: ");
        String searchTerm = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number of query results: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q=" + searchTerm + "&num=" + num;

        //NEED TO DEFINE USER AGENT TO PREVENT 403 ERROR.
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();

        //OPTION TO DISPLAY HTML FILE IN BROWSWER. DON'T KNOW YET.
        //System.out.println(doc.html());

        //If google search results HTML change the <h3 class="r" to <h3 class ="r1"
        //need to change below stuff accordingly
        Elements results = document.select("h3.r > a");

        index = 0;
        String news = "News";
        for (Element result : results) {

            index++;
            linkHref = result.attr("href");
            String linkText = result.text();
            String pingResult = index + ": " + linkText + ", URL:: " + linkHref.substring(6, linkHref.indexOf("&"));
            if (pingResult.contains(news)) {
                System.out.println("FOUND " + "\"" + linkText + "\"" + "NO HYPERTEXT FOR NEWS QUERY RESULTS AT THIS TIME. SKIPPED INDEX.");
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println(pingResult);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();


        goToURL(linkHref, input);
    }

    public static int goToURL(String hRef, Scanner input) {

        try {

            System.out.print("Enter Index (i.e. 1, 2, etc) you wish to visit, 0 to exit: ");

            int newIndex = input.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {

                if (newIndex == index) {
/*
RUNNING LINUX COMMAND WITH RUNTIME CLASS TO COCANTENATE THE HYPERLINK SUBSTRING
*/
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open " + hRef.substring(6, hRef.indexOf("&"))); 
                    process.waitFor();
                    break;
                } else if (newIndex == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Shutting program down.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR while parsing URL");
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

**HERE IS THE OUTPUT**
It stops before the new Scanner can take input

```
Search: Oracle
Enter number of query results: 3
1: Oracle | Integrated Cloud Applications and Platform Services, URL:: =http://www.oracle.com/
2: Oracle Corporation - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia, URL:: =https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation
3: Oracle (@Oracle) | Twitter, URL:: =https://twitter.com/oracle%3Flang%3Den


Enter Index (i.e. 1, 2, etc) you wish to visit, 0 to exit: Shutting program down.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, it goes straight to the else statment to shut the program down.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is a fun project, and I look forward to completing it.

Comment: Use the same scanner instance in all the places if you want to read from the `standard input`. That should solve the issue.

Comment: Alright. I removed the new Scanner and put it in the parameters of the goToURL method (String hRef, Scanner input). It allows me to enter a number, but the program now stops after entering input. But, hey, progress!

Comment: The problem is that whenever you close the `Scanner` instance you also close the underlying `InputStream` (which is `stdin`), so the subsequent `Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in)` relies on an already closed `InputStream`. Result: no more input for you! ;)

Comment: I will gladly edit my question to include the now kept-open Scanner for the sake of further comment confusion. :)

Comment: Removed else statement.

Comment: I believe another problem is in my for loop. I just need to figure out how to loop through the indices listed in the console output to recognize my new user integer as the index I wanna go to.

Comment: Your question seems to evolved into something entirely different than what it was at start. If you solved original problem post your solution as answer, so others could learn from it. Don't simply change your code which won't let others see the problem. Also if you have follow-up question ask it in new question so people could focus only on that problem.

Comment: I honestly didn't know how the SO community would feel about me asking a new question with the same code, but that's a completely valid point. I will correct this now. Thanks for the constructive tip. My apologies for not considering that.

Comment: I am not saying about posting exact same code. You can post new one, add information that this is follow-up question and explain main difference in both code examples (like what you already corrected and what is new problem). BTW if you are responding to someones comment it is good practice to add `@nickOfThatPerson` in your comment like in my case `@Pshemo`. This way I will be informed about your response.

Comment: Also you you may try not to post your entire code at all. It is even preferred to create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows exact problem you are facing.

Comment: See, that part of SO confuses me. I wasn't sure how to create an SSCCE so someone could compile and run without including everything. Any suggestions for next time? I've read that link, and didn't quite gather the suggestions.

Comment: (you need to practice using `@nick` in your comments, I wasn't aware you answered my previous comment) Anyway try to avoid things which are not needed in code examples, like asking user for dynamic content if it doesn't really matter. Simply hardcode some fixed values. So instead of `"gimme some number" value = readInt()` simply write `value = 42;`. Also remove comments which are not needed like those which are comment-out code which is not used. Things like that should reduce amount of code a little which can prevent others from running away from your question.

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Per the suggestion of an SO team member, I asked why Scanner was not asking for input. Technically speaking, I fixed the problem with the program stopping **BEFORE** getting input. Though a problem still exists where it is not actually processing the input, the previous problem was fixed and here is my solution.

I did not close the original Scanner, and added the Scanner as a parameter to my "goToURL" method. I also removed an else statement that was closing the program, as the input to allow the program to keep running is still buggy. Nonetheless, here is the "working" code that at least solves the original problem.

Additionally, I placed the String elements (pingResult) into an ArrayList to improve the loop structure in the goToURL method. I felt this was a decent way to go about using a simple data structure for accessing elements:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class GoogleSearchJava {

    static int index;
    static String linkHref;

    public static final String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //GET INPUT FOR SEARCH TERM

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Search: ");
        String searchTerm = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number of query results: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q=" + searchTerm + "&num=" + num;

        //NEED TO DEFINE USER AGENT TO PREVENT 403 ERROR.
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();

        //OPTION TO DISPLAY HTML FILE IN BROWSWER. DON'T KNOW YET.
        //System.out.println(doc.html());

        //If google search results HTML change the <h3 class="r" to <h3 class ="r1"
        //need to change below stuff accordingly
        Elements results = document.select("h3.r > a");

        index = 0;
        String news = "News";
        /*
        THIS WILL ADD THE pingResult STRINGS TO AN ARRAYLIST
        */
        ArrayList<String> displayResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element result : results) {
            index++;
            linkHref = result.attr("href");
            String linkText = result.text();
            String pingResult = index + ": " + linkText + ", URL:: " + linkHref.substring(6, linkHref.indexOf("&")) + "\n";

            if (pingResult.contains(news)) {
                System.out.println("FOUND " + "\"" + linkText + "\"" + "NO HYPERTEXT FOR NEWS QUERY RESULTS AT THIS TIME. SKIPPED INDEX.");
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                displayResults.add(pingResult);
            }
        }
        for(String urlString : displayResults) {
            System.out.println(urlString);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();


        goToURL(linkHref, input, displayResults);
    }

    public static int goToURL(String hRef, Scanner input, ArrayList<String> resultList) {

        try {

            System.out.print("Enter Index (i.e. 1, 2, etc) you wish to visit, 0 to exit: ");

            index = input.nextInt();

            for (String string : resultList) {

                if (string.startsWith(Integer.toString(index))) {

                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open " + hRef.substring(6, hRef.indexOf("&")));
                    process.waitFor();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR while parsing URL");
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```